# What should I tell my father?

Tags: sufism

My father sometimes looks at horoscopes and seems to believe in some omens. When I said that it was not right, he said that only wahhabis say that. He also watches the dhikr of sufis who repeat the names of their "righteous". He said they were repeating the name of a "good" person. But he prays and fasts during the month of Ramadan. What should I tell my father?